# Inside react router componet, a tag, link is add to curr url

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

Inside a `react-router` component when I am using `<a>` tag with external link, the link is appended to current url of the application and routing me to there.

```
<a
  href={job.profileId.website}
  target="_blank"
  className="text-blue-600 hover:underline"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
  {job.profileId.website}
</a>
```

ex: `"http://127.0.0.1:5173/www.website.com"`

I am using "react": "^18.2.0", "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1"

I have tried researching and asked to chatGPT, but found no solution. Maybe this is `react-router` error, but can be solved by any other method?

Comment: You need to use the react router `Link` component. Instead of cutting corners with ChatGPT you should read the react router documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with `react-router`, and `react-router` doesn't handle external links. The issue here is with the literal link target value being used not being a valid absolute URL. `"www.website.com"` is being treated as a relative path, so it's appended to the current URL, e.g. `"http://127.0.0.1:5173/www.website.com"`.

If you want to link to an external URL then the link target should look something more like `"https://www.website.com"`. You can either create the valid URL path with something like `` href={`https://${job.profileId.website}`} ``:

```
<a
  href={`https://${job.profileId.website}`}
  target="_blank"
  className="text-blue-600 hover:underline"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
  {job.profileId.website}
</a>
```

or update the `job.profileId.website` property value to be the complete absolute URL like `job.profileId.website = "https://www.website.com"` so `href={job.profileId.website}` has the link value you need.

Comment: i should also process website link when talking input from user to remove https, if it is added in the input link, or add if https is missing.
is there any error in routing if link is http / https

Comment: @prabal Are you asking about internal routing using the `Router` and `Route` components? I don't think you'll want "http(s)" in the route/link paths unless it is just something that is part of the URL path part like <Route path="/httpsPage" .... />`.